# NodeJS Conditional Server Startup

Tags: node.js

Is there any way in node.js wherein I can start a server on a condition.
Suppose I want to load some parameters from DB into memory and if the load is successful, then only start the server else don't start.

I am a bit of a new to node.js and this seems quite a beginners question. Is it possible?

In fact, I created a conditional server start-up but I am getting the below error every time.

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3007
  at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
  at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
```

And I did a lookup for my application and it was not running at all. After that, I tried changing my port multiple times but no luck. The error seems persistent.

Comment: checkout gulp or some similar task automation tool, these support conditional task execution

Comment: I am looking for server startup... Did you go through my question. I dont think i need a tool for starting the server in the above mentioned scenario. There could be some other way.

Comment: Yes I read your question, the thing is how else you would you startup a script if not using some automation tool so that it is only done when a certain condition is met, but then again you could change the idea to exit the program after checking if data is not loaded else let it run as usual

Comment: Also see if any process running is using the port by executing `sudo lsof -n -i :80`because the error says 3007 port is already in use.

Comment: Whatever port I start on, even if i chnage the port as well, i get the same error.

Comment: Could you please post how is it that you are starting it. "In fact I created a conditional server start-up", what did you mean by that?